# Converting jpg image with white background to transparent background png when image object also has white color

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert few JPG files with white background to PNG with transparent background.
I am using the following command:

```html
convert 2868cif.jpg -fuzz 10% -transparent white 2868cif.png
```

The command works fine on most of the images. But for images with white content it converts them to as white. refer to sample images below:

**Original image**
[image]

**convert image**
[image]

In logical terms, I can understand why this is happening. I just wanted to know if there is a workaround for this using imagemagick?

Comment: did you resolve this problem ? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try floodfill with transparent color:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" output.png
```